# How to add sub menu in mean.io?

Tags: submenu, mean.io

I've been wandering around the internet to find a way to add submenu's to the mean.io application.

```
  SystemPackage.menus.add({
    title: 'Log Out',
    link: 'Log Out',
    roles: ['authenticated'],
    menu: 'account'
  });
```

I've the following questions from the above code.

- What is the purpose of `menu` property in the object passed to add?
- Does mean.io have any configuration to support submenu? If so, how to configure it?

Answer (score 5):

This is not currently possible to support submenus. The menu service is defined in the menu controller located in 
"mean/packages/core/system/public/controllers/header.js" on the github repo. Within the code, there is no recursive implementation to identify and process sub-menu definitions.

Here's the source controller to view for yourself:

- https://github.com/linnovate/mean/blob/master/packages/core/system/public/controllers/header.js

Comment: Yeah.. But as per this (https://github.com/linnovate/meanio/blob/master/lib/menu.js) the submenu option should be available in the mean package menus. This is a node module used for constructing the menu object in Mean.io.